# Range should use the selected cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection, cells

I'm trying to run a Makro which should use the selected cell as Range.

Instead of Range("B1") it should be something like Range("selectedCell")

My code is like this, and I would like the makro to split the data in the selected cell.

```
Sub tst()
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("B11").Value, ",")
Range("B11").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Range("B11").Value`, you can use `Selection.Value`.

`Selection` can be more than 1 cell, so you should probably check for that first.

Comment: You have to do some pre-checks... if there are more than one cell selected, Selection.Value would trigger an error.

Comment: @varocarbas You're right. I was already editing my response. :-)

Comment: OK. A condition checking that is pretty easy (via Selection.Columns.Count or Selection.Row.Count being greater than 1, for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
  range(selection.address)
```

keep it simple :)